# HttpTwo.HPack dll is present in the bin folder but it is not appearing in the references of my project

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification

ERROR :
--Could not load file or assembly 'Http Two, Version=1.0.5858.36836, Culture=neutral, ----Public Key Token=e33b67d3bb5581e4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified .":"Http Two, Version=1.0.5858.36836, Culture=neutral, Public Key Token=e33b67d3bb5581e4

Comment: This often means that it cannot find a *dependency* of HttpTwo, not necessarily HttpTwo itself, you should check if it has any dependency and if it does, put the DLL along in the bin directory

Comment: The dll has already in bin folder then too it is throwing an above error.